# Creating a subplot from barplot in R

Tags: r

I have a barplot and I would like to create a subplot from barplot which includes just the first and second column, how can I do this in R? I wrote the following code but it does not work properly.

```
   library(package="TeachingDemos")
   barplot(c(.1, .2, .3,.4), space=0, ylim=c(0, 1))
   lines(c(0, 1, 2, 3), y=c(.1, .2, .3, .4), col="blue",lty=2)
   op <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
   new = subplot(
   barplot(c(.1, .2, .3, .4), space=0, xlim=c(0, 2), ylim=c(0, 0.001), xlab="", ylab= "", lwd=2),  grconvertX(.1,from='npc'), grconvertY(0.25,from='npc'), 
   vadj=0, hadj=0 , size=c(1, .5))
   op <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
   new1 = subplot(
   lines(c(0, 1, 2, 3),c(.1, .2, .3, .4), col="blue", lwd =2, lty = 2, type="l", xlim=c(0, .5),     ylim=c(0, 0.02), xlab="", ylab="", labels = FALSE),
   grconvertX(.1,from='npc'), grconvertY(0.25,from='npc'), vadj=0, hadj=0 , size=c(1, .5))
   par(new)
   par(new1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your `ylim` needs to be adjusted for the data you have, as well as the fact that you want to be plotting the first two elements in the `c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)` vector.

Maybe the `par(..., fig=c(), new=T)` helps you?

```
# Begin plotting
par(oma=c(rep(1,4)),ps=12,fig=c(0,1,0,1))
barplot(c(.1, .2, .3,.4), space=0, ylim=c(0, 1))
lines(c(0, 1, 2, 3), y=c(.1, .2, .3, .4), col="blue",lty=2)

# Begin the sub-plot 1
par(fig=c(0.2,0.6,0.5,0.95),oma=c(0,1,0,0),new=T)
# You need to only plot the values you needed: I updated ylim to reflect this too.
barplot(c(.1, .2), space=0, xlim=c(0, 2), ylim=c(0, 0.3), xlab="", ylab= "", lwd=2)
box(lty='solid',col='black')

# Begin the sub-plot 2
par(fig=c(0.6,1,0.5,0.95),oma=c(0,1,0,0),new=T)
lines(c(0, 1),c(.1, .2), col="blue", lwd =2, lty = 2, type="l", xlim=c(0, .5),     ylim=c(0, 0.3), xlab="", ylab="")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but here is code based on yours that works:

```
library(package="TeachingDemos")

barplot(c(.1, .2, .3,.4), space=0, ylim=c(0, 1))

lines(c(0, 1, 2, 3), y=c(.1, .2, .3, .4), col="blue",lty=2)

op <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)

new <- subplot(
    barplot(c(.1, .2, .3, .4)[1:2], space=0, xlim=c(0, 2), ylim=c(0, 0.2), 
        xlab="", ylab= "", lwd=2),  
    grconvertX(.1,from='npc'), grconvertY(0.25,from='npc'), 
    vadj=0, hadj=0 , size=c(1, .5))

tmp <- par(new)
lines( c(0,1,2,3)[1:2], c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)[1:2], col='blue', lwd=2, lty=2 )
par(tmp)
```

The `subplot` function is not used for lower level functions, rather you set the parameters with the return from `subplot` then add to the subplot, then reset the parameters back.  Also, if you want to show only part of the plot by using `xlim` and `ylim` then the clipping region needs to be set, some plotting functions do this automatically, but it looks like `barplot` does not.  You may be able to fix this using `clip` and/or other functions, but I think it is simplest to just make the plot so it does not need to be clipped (I subsetted the data in the example).